# PHP Goutte try and retry

Tags: php, web-crawler, guzzle, goutte

I need to crawl some data from a website. Some of the reasons for the target server, some crawl can not succeed, need to retry.The code is as follows:

```
private function fetchArchive($id) {
        $url = 'xxxx/' . $id;

        $attempt = 0;
        $base = null;
        if (Goutte::request('GET', $url)->filter('#table')->count() < 1) {
            do {
                try {
                    $base = Goutte::request('GET', $url)->filter('#table')->text();
                } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
                    $attempt++;
                    sleep(2);
                    break;
                }

            } while ($attempt <= 5);
        }
```

In fact `try($base = Goutte::request('GET', $url)->filter('#table')->text())` does not work and I recieve

> "production.ERROR: InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty."

how do I fixed this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `\InvalidArgumentException` (from the root namespace, yes).

Also consider to retry on the HTTP level, using a Guzzle's middleware (like in [this example](https://addshore.com/2015/12/guzzle-6-retry-middleware/)). It's better, because you handle exactly HTTP related errors in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Because I used Laravel, so:

```
catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {...}
```